# Attempting a circular image, outputs a diamond shape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a weird issue coming up. I am parsing data and pulling out a URL for an image, then setting it to a cell's '`imageView`'. From what I can understand, I should set the size of the '`cornerRadius`' to half the image's height. Because I am pulling the data into a table view cell with a height of 100, I am setting the corner radius to 50.

Yet when the view load's on the first initial load of the images, they are coming out as small diamonds. When I rotate the device (which rotates the table view too), it automatically brings back the full size image, with the roundness too.

Here's an example image of the initial load,

[image]

Does anybody know why this occurs?

Here is my tableView code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSDictionary *generatedUsers = [self.randomlyGeneratedUsersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[generatedUsers valueForKeyPath:@"user.picture"]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [generatedUsers valueForKeyPath:@"user.name.first"], [generatedUsers valueForKeyPath:@"user.name.last"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [generatedUsers valueForKeyPath:@"user.location.street"];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]];

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: it is right when your cell height is 100.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure something like Auto-Layout isn't changing your imageView height at runtime?
try setting the corner radius like this:

```
cell.imageView.layer.corderRadius = (cell.imageView.bounds.size.height /2);
//And to try figure out what's going on...
NSLog(@"Cell imageview height: %f",cell.imageView.bounds.size.height);
```

Comment: +1 was just going to post same, you beat me so didn't post. Cheers.

Comment: @Dermot So yours gave me the idea to use NSLog to find what the height is being outputted as, and it is returning 0.000000. I've also turned off Autolayout to see if it would change anything at all, and it looks like it hadn't.

Comment: Hmm, is is your imageView nil? Obj-C can send messages to nil objects without throwing an exception, so your current code would not cause an error if imageView is nil. Try NSLog(@"Image view is %@",(imageView ? @"not nil" : @"nil"));

Answer (score 1):

In the place of this 2 line of code

```
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0f;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Put this to line of code

```
[cell.imageView.layer setCornerRadius:cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2];
 [cell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the corner radius to be half the height of the image, not the table cell.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imageView.frame.size.height/2;
```

Comment: This was something I had been trying, but because the imageView bounds size height is returning 0, it doesn't work. I'm now trying to figure out why that is.

Comment: try setting contentmode property of imageView.